# Does a column contain certain part of the other column string? (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to check if a column string is contained in the other column.

Table emaillist:

```
    complete_email
---------------------------------
    zazumba@hotmail.com
    jere@yahoo.com
    maryhelp@aol.com
    neil@cde.de
    john_smith@zodll.ne
```

Table emailpartial:

```
    username
--------------------
    zazumba
    maryhelp
    neil
```

The query I want to perform:

```
select e.complete_email 
   from emailslist e, emailpartial ep 
      where e.complete_email like '%ep.username%';
```

I would expect a result like:

```
    complete_email
---------------------------
    zazumba@hotmail.com
    maryhelp@aol.com
    neil@cde.de
```

However, it is not the right way of writing this sql query. Can someone clarify how can I write it?

Thanks, Samuel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do believe what you are looking for is:

```
select e.complete_email 
from emailslist e, emailpartial ep 
where e.complete_email like '%' || ep.username || '%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in function `strpos()`:

```
select e.complete_email 
from emailslist e
join emailpartial ep 
  on strpos(e.complete_email, ep.username) > 0
```

which avoids unnecessary concatenation required if `like` is used.

Note that it's best practice to code joins using proper join syntax.

Comment: This is more elegant like you said and I would pick this for most purposes. I tested and found that `LIKE` is twice as fast in seq scans, though (v9.3). More importantly, `strpos()` can't use an available [trigram index (as opposed to `LIKE`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528).